# I want to solve the sorting algorithm problem

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, qsort

First I input list size variable is n and get n date data entered day, month, year.

I want to make date array using the structure.

and I want to sort the date data with qsort in c

ex)
20, 1, 2014 / 25,  3, 2010 / 3, 12, 1676 / 18, 11, 1982 / 19,  4, 2015 / 9,  7, 2015

->

3, 12, 1676 / 18, 11, 1982 / 25,  3, 2010/ 20,  1, 2014/ 19,  4, 2015 / 9,  7, 2015

but I can't solve it for some reason.

I want hear about some comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct date{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
}date;

bool compare(const date *d1, const date *d2){
    if(d1->year < d2->year){
        return true;
    }
    if (d1->year == d2->year && d1->month < d2->month){
        return true;
    }
    if (d1->year == d2->year && d1->month == d2->month && d1->day < d2->day){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

int main(void){
    int n;
    int i;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    date data[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d %d %d", &data[i].day, &data[i].month, &data[i].year);
    }
    qsort(data, n, sizeof(data)/sizeof(date) ,compare);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d %d %d \n",data[i].day,data[i].month,data[i].year);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, for starters, [read the documentation of `qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort). The comparator doesn't return true or false, it returns negative (less), zero (equivalent), or positive (greater) when determining the relationship of the two items being compared. You'll find standard library function work considerably better when you follow the rules they set forth on how to actually use them. Relating to the code, it would bolster your confidence *considerably* if you verify each and ever input you're currently accepting as successful on blind faith actually succeed.

Comment: `sizeof(data)/sizeof(date)` is also wrong. That argument should be `sizeof *data` or just `sizeof(date)` .

Comment: @WhozCraig Is there no problem with the purpose of the code?

Comment: I have no idea what that even *means*. You're going to have to elaborate.

Comment: @WhozCraig umm I wonder if the code is well-organized for the purpose of the algorithm problem, except for return and sizeof, where it needs to be fixed.

Comment: **Turn on and mind your compiler warnings.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `qsort` comparator is wrong. The standard library function expects a function taking two `const void *` arguments and returning an `int` value, denoting negative (less), zero (equivalent), or positive (greater) when determining the relationship of the two items being compared. Further, your third argument to `qsort` is wrong as well. It is the size of **an** item (singular) in the sequence being sorted, not the count of items (which you've already provided as the second argument).

Fixing those, as well as validating input (don't assume anything), the result is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct date
{
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
} date;

int compare(const void *arg1, const void * arg2)
{
    const date *d1 = arg1;
    const date *d2 = arg2;

    int res = (d1->year < d2->year) ? -1 : (d2->year < d1->year);
    
    if (res == 0)
    {
        res = (d1->month < d2->month) ? -1 : (d2->month < d1->month);
    }

    if (res == 0)
    {
        res = (d1->day < d2->day) ? -1 : (d2->day < d1->day);
    }

    return res;
}

int main(void)
{
    int n;
    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1 && n > 0)
    {
        date data[n];
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < n; ++i)
        {
            if (scanf("%d %d %d", &data[i].day, &data[i].month, &data[i].year) != 3)
                break;
        }

        if (i > 0)
        {
            n = i;
            qsort(data, n, sizeof *data, compare);
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                printf("%d %d %d \n", data[i].day, data[i].month, data[i].year);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Whether that ultimately matches your *real* input data is another matter entirely. I suspect it won't since dates typically have slashes, dashes, etc. You're probably going to have to spend some time on the actual data parsing of the input values. But at least teh sorting part is taken care of now.